# VLCMediaPlayer initWithLibrary not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, vlc, libvlc, vlckit

I try to load a m3u file with an user agent, I use the `VLCMediaPlayer initWithLibrary`
but that not work
there is my code

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tStream.m3u"];

VLCLibrary *myLib = [VLCLibrary sharedLibrary];

[myLib setHumanReadableName:@"Idontknow" withHTTPUserAgent:@"myUserAgent"];

_mediaPlayerOne = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithLibrary:myLib];

_mediaOne = [VLCMedia mediaWithPath:filePath];

_mediaPlayerOne.media = _mediaOne;
    
[_mediaPlayerOne play];
```

Someone knows where my problem comes from ?
Thank You

Comment: We can't help you debug without debug details. What's the actual problem?

Comment: The problem is when I try to load a m3u file with an http-user-agent that not load the m3u file, that work perfectly without http-user-agent. In log file is just have this lines : creating player instance using shared library AND  HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -999

Comment: VLCLibrary log return this line : [ERR] Failed reading http:/ /theStreamURL:8080/XXXXX/XXXXX/140:  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized